# Razor-Pages - HTML markup

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Following the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810965/how-to-add-html-to-the-page-inside-a-razor-if-statement-in-a-foreach) I was using `@:<div class="col-md-6">`

**Problems**

- The Formatting gets all messed up:

[image]

- The intellicode gets all messed up (I only deleted the paragraph on the second `@:`)

[image]

- Also, my `if (i == (Model.CellsNotStarted.Count - 1) && i % 2 != 0)` won't work when using the `@:`; it will always go on the else. If I don't use the `@:` markup, and if I, for instance put **all** my html in a `if/else` instead of only the `<div>` tag it will work with no problems.

My question is:
Is the `@:` markup viable? If so, what am I doing wrong. If not what is the alternative (that does not imply putting my entire code in an `if/else`)

**PS:** I know I should not post images of code, but I wanted to show the format and syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are neater ways to manage conditions within your Razor code. It's difficult to provide a full example because you don't provide the full code, but you can do this, for example:

```
<div class="col-md-@(i+1 == Model.CellsNotStarted.Count && i % 2 ! = 0 ? "12" : "6")">
```

Whenever you are tempted to use a remainder operator (`%`) in Razor, you should also consider whether a `GroupBy` would be better. It most often is, as I was shown in this question:  [Building tables with WebMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639387/building-tables-with-webmatrix)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use js to set html.Here is a demo:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
        $(function () {
            var html = "";
            if ("@(Model.CellsNotStarted != null)"=="True")
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <@Model.CellsNotStarted.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == (@Model.CellsNotStarted.Count - 1) && i % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        html += '<div class="col-md-12">';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        html += '<div class="col-md-6">';
                    }
                    html += i+'</div>';

                }
            }
            $("#myDiv").html(html);


        })
</script>
```

result:
[image]